# mvc3 formauthentication username to int value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, form-authentication

I am using the formauthentication and as the user.identity.name I am using they're email, How can I change it to were I can use they're unique Registration ID instead?

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,model.Email, DateTime.Now, cookieExpiration, true,model.Email);
```

The model.Email is the Email that the users have and its a String parameter I instead would like to put **model.RegistrationID** .

Comment: What exactly is stopping you from just trying `model.RegistrationID.ToString()`?

Comment: That throws me an error for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change its data type but you can do what you want by keeping the `RegistrationId` in the database as string.

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket= new FormsAuthenticationTicket(RegistrationId.ToString() ,model.Email, DateTime.Now,cookieExpiration, true,model.Email);
```

Comment: Thank you that worked, created another field string and convert to int.